# Calling function inside function in another function

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in `iOS Programming`, and I had this problem. Let's say I have these two function:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, ErrorMessageDelegate {
    var uiView =  UIView();
    var viewErrorMessage:ErrorMessage!

    func refresh(_sender: AnyObject) {
        print("testing")
    }

    func getErrorMessage(message:String) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Dialog.dismiss()
        ErrorMessage.message = message
        viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ErrorMessage
        viewErrorMessage.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)

        func removeSubView() {
            viewErrorMessage.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call function **removeSubView** inside function **refresh**. I had to do that because I need to override **refresh** function to my subclass. And I need to put the function **removeSubView** in **getErrorMessage** because I should to. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried it by writing the method outside the `getErrorMessage` method?

Comment: This is not Swift only. This is because you don't have access to other scopes. I would suggest moving `removeSubView()` to an accessible scope inside your `BaseViewController()`, you can make it private to prevent others from calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer below code. It will help you to resolve the issue.

**Code:**

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, ErrorMessageDelegate {
    var uiView =  UIView();
    var viewErrorMessage:ErrorMessage!

    func refresh(_sender: AnyObject) {
        removeSubView()
    }

    func getErrorMessage(message:String) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Dialog.dismiss()
        ErrorMessage.message = message
        viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ErrorMessage
        viewErrorMessage.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)
    }
    func removeSubView() {
        viewErrorMessage.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible

```
func a() {
    c()
}

func b() {
    c()
}

func c() {
    print("hello world")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no it is not possible - but I wonder why you would do that?

Comment: What does removeSubview() have to do with getErrorMessage()? Nothing. So there is no reason for it to be at the scope of getErrorMessage

Comment: viewErrorMessage has to be called inside getErrrorMessage because it added there

Comment: @FirdaSahidi Well move it out